# using scheduleAtFixedRate and Schedule method for newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, threadpool

I followed the following link to implement a single thread scheduled Executor

[Link to example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.util.concurrent/ExecutorsnewSingleThreadScheduledExecutor.htm)

I am a bit confused at why the **schedule** method is invoked after the **scheduleAtFixedRate** method.

What exactly is the reason for having the schedule method here?

Comment: It is a Question and Answer site. You should ask specific question. Visit [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question.

Comment: thanks will take note

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is used to cancel the periodic task after 1 hour

Comment: What I understood from your comment is - A particular execution can last for 1 hour, but the Scheduler will continue to run indefinitely am I correct?

Comment: First task will execute every 10 secs forever unless you cancel it. Second task is scheduled to run once after one hour and cancel the first task